# ошибка: 'connect' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

Добавил один класс в проект. Выдает ошибку ошибка:

```
'connect' was not declared in this scope
                                                        ^
```

Пытался добавить `QObject::connect(...)`- Результат тот же

Заголовочный файл

```
#include "httphelper.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QEventLoop>

HttpHelper::HttpHelper()
{

}

void HttpHelper::GetHtml()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://qt-project.org"));
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);

    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(request);

    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();

    QString html = response->readAll(); // Source should be stored here
}
```

Вот его cpp-файл

```
#ifndef HTTPHELPER_H
#define HTTPHELPER_H
#include <QObject>


class HttpHelper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HttpHelper();
    void GetHtml();
};

#endif // HTTPHELPER_H
```

Comment: и откуда ты магически желаешь получить функцию connect?

Comment: попробуйте добавить макрос Q_OBJECT в заголовочный файл

Comment: я добавлял. тоже самое

Comment: унаследоваться ты не забыл?

Comment: можно чуток поподробее?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20932636/5006740. функции connect неоткуда взяться, если ее нет в самом классе, или нет в глобальном пространстве имен. получить ее в классе можно или объявив (но это не ваш вариант) или унаследовавшись от qobject. кажется, логично. Вам явно нужно слегка прокачать понимание областей видимости в c++

Comment: спасибо за ответ, пробую наследоваться от QObject. http://s018.radikal.ru/i525/1607/f6/71f16b25d78b.png

Comment: а либы кто прилинковывать будет?

Comment: какие именно\? include Qobject ?

Comment: Добавь в свой `.pro` строку `QT += network`

Comment: Уже добавил. Все равно такая же ошибка

Comment: https://github.com/Radzhab/QTparser